# sideNavBox cannnot do responsive on Master Page

Tags: sharepoint, responsive-design, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Why my sideNavBox can't be responsive? I tried to apply col-md-3 to my sideNavBox and it shows me like this, It seems that sideNavBox causing something not to move?

[image]

Here is my Full Master Page code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6e3b76d1d621903f7262920234c3e37

Comment: Can you check Under Site Actions, in Manage site features the Mobile Browser View feature is Active?

Comment: Yes it's already active bro